# Genealogy SE needs some new leadership. Is it you?

Tags: discussion, moderation

I've recently been on the lookout for a new pro-tem moderator for Genealogy. Unfortunately, I've had a bit of trouble finding an enthusiastic,  dedicated individual to take part in some community building. So, I am turning to meta.

**A bit about the job, and what we're looking for:**

Much like the community leaders in a small town who ensure that roads get fixed, trees get planted, and trash gets removed, each Stack Exchange site needs a team of three moderators who see to it that the site is able to continue to be a productive resource.

Ideal candidates should:

- Want the responsibility, and have at least a few hours each week to give on average
- Be consistently patient and fair in their dealings with the community
- Be knowledgeable enough about the topic to be able to judge the quality of posts, and identify cleverly crafted spam
- Be ready to lead the community to help you do your jobs. Teach people how to flag properly, encourage a culture of editors and strong reviewers
- Work directly with me and the rest of the SE community team to make sure this community is getting its needs met from us
- Understand and embrace our [theory of moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

Are you interested? Great! Send me an email at ana at stackexchangedotcom to indicate your desire to be considered. While I will consider third-party nominations, I'd rather see nominations from folks enthused enough to step in and write something down.

I aim to have someone appointed in a week's time, so don't hesitate to jump in.

---

**UPDATE:** Many thanks to the excellent people who came forward. Keep your eyes peeled, we'll have a new third mod on Genealogy very soon.

Comment: Thanks for the update. That's very good news.

Answer (score 4):

Hopefully a candidate or two may have already contacted @Ana but, in case no one has, and anyone is in two minds about whether to do so, and what is holding them back is concern about the workload, I wish to reassure them that at our current question rate the *required* workload only amounts to about an hour a week.

As our question rate picks up this may become a little more, but if it does, then our reward will be graduation, and the opportunity for a moderator election to follow that.  Becoming a [Pro Tem (appointed) moderator](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) now can be a great stepping stone to being an elected moderator later, but equally, anyone who may have concerns about the workload during the remainder of Beta, could use that election as an opportunity to step aside if the workload does turn out to be more than anticipated.

I think anyone who is thinking "should I, or shouldn't I put my hand up" definitely should.