# Why is this Q&A site still tagged Beta?

Tags: discussion, graduation

When is this site going to be taken out of the **Beta** stage?

From what I can tell it has been established for several years.

Comment: Andrew, it would be good if you weren't so quick to accept answers, here or on the main site. I know PolyGeo is likely to have a different perspective to mine, and I recommend waiting for them to weigh in.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl I have patiently waited on many questions. But I did no see the point in delaying for this one. Your answer is factual and to the point. What I wish is that people were not so quick to down vote. I would prefer constructive criticism. If you see any particular reason why I should un-accept your answer for the benefit of others then I will.

Comment: I suspect @PolyGeo won't be put off answering by the fact that you've accepted an answer but others might. The same applies on the main site -- once you accept an answer it discourages the addition of other answers.

Comment: Also, downvoting *is* constructive criticism: it tells you that somebody considers that your question 'doesn't show any research effort; is unclear or not useful.'  Here, I suspect that the downvote is either because you didn't demonstrate that you'd searched and reference existing meta questions on the subject ("no research effort") or because somebody thought the question was not useful. But I'm guessing -- which is exactly how it should be -- nobody has to justify a downvote.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl Fair points. But note - is all of my years in SO, in all of this flavours - I have never said to myself "Hey - go over and see what is on meta". Family Tree stuff is a hobby for me. But as with many of us, I got to where I am with hard work. As a programmer I am self taught got most things and then freely share my knowledge on SO. Anyways, I do appreciate your comments and insight on the matters you raised. Thank you.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl But if there are multiple answers, and they are both good, I then don't know who to accept! Hohum!

Comment: Don't accept either of them. Especially on Meta.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl Why? It is good to show that a question has been "answered" to the point of satisfaction. I am even flagged sometimes by the SO system to indicate if proposed answers were good enough and to "accept" one. I think it is fair for a user to "accept" an answer - not that it is a "rush" to get your answer in. And then, if it is not about gaining reputation, a user should not care if it has been answered, if they have another bit of info to add, then answer anyway. They'll still get a vote from me. :) Got to go to work now ...

Comment: Main is different from meta -- there, yes, it's important to indicate an accepted (correct) answer. Not that everybody always accepts a correct answer of course! And if you genuinely can't distinguish between two answers, leave other votes to indicate which is 'best' by the number of votes.

Comment: Also, SO and G & FH have different site cultures -- don't assume the norms there are the norms here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SE set the standards for moving sites out of beta -- which are a combination of question volumes, quality and community activity. About 18 months ago they moved a number of sites out of beta status as they had been active for about 7 years, but we just missed out. See [Missed it by that much(](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3436/6485)

It's important to realise that moving out of beta would have some implications for us that we might not be happy with -- in particular the reputation thresholds for carrying out some actions would go up significantly, to the extent that many of our users might no longer be able to participate in moderation activities. We have problems mustering 5 close votes (we have asked for the threshold to be lower to 3 but it's stuck in the backlog of Community Manager workload).  If the reputation threshold for casting close votes went up from 500 (the level on a beta site) to 3000 (the level on a graduated site) we would struggle even more.

Benefits if we graduated? Yes, we'd lose the beta label. Site designs don't happen these days... but you would get to elect your moderators. Other than that I can't think of any benefits.

We might feel 'safer' from being closed down but [Good news about our outlook -- we can stop worrying about graduation](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2029/6485) explains why that isn't a real issue as long as we keep the place clean and tidy and useful.

We could always do with more **good quality** questions, and honestly, we're not getting enough of those at present, so that's something we should strive to improve. For the rest, IMO, stop worrying about it.

Answer (score 1):

I do not disagree with anything said in [@ColeValleyGirl's answer](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3508/19) but I weigh the pros and cons they present differently.

I would like to see our Beta label removed at the earliest opportunity and have asked for that to happen in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/331728/215590) to [Congratulations to our 29 oldest beta sites - They're now no longer beta!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331708/congratulations-to-our-29-oldest-beta-sites-theyre-now-no-longer-beta) which is slowly accumulating upvotes.

I am confident that when we have five "greens" (Excellent) at https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/43502/genealogy-family-history our case to leave Beta will be rock solid and, in the meantime, any "reds" (Needs Work) will weaken it greatly.

[image]